# Phone reception puzzle

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

My wife and I both have 2013 vintage moto g phones using the GiffGaff network. My phone gets decent enough reception, whereas my wife struggles to get reception most of the time (for instance see is currently talking on my phone because her phone didn't get reception). I just wondered whether there was a possible software reason for the difference in performance? Or is it likely that my wife has just dropped it and broken/weakened something inside?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when I was in the UK using a giffgaff SIM on my Moto (Marshmallow). My daughter's phone was getting a signal when I couldn't get one bar. Checking my APN settings to ensure they were as giffgaff intended solved the problem.

Assuming you both have exactly the same set up otherwise, if the APN setting is different or non-existent on one of the phones, your wife's phone may be trying to connect to the wrong network (or, if she has roaming disabled, she may not have a network to connect to).

First guess? Check APN settings are what giffgaff gave as the settings. It may be that hers are different from yours because for whatever reason giffgaff had the SIM cards set to use different networks. So check the text which provided that information on her phone as well as yours.